# Google analytics HitBuilder addProduct not working

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics

I am adding product to GA Hitbuilder it is working fine but data not reflected in dashboard yet following is my code

```
com.google.android.gms.analytics.ecommerce.Product product = new com.google.android.gms.analytics.ecommerce.Product();
                        product.setId(dealItem.dealId)
                                .setName(dealItem.title)
                                .setCategory(dealItem.dealCategory)
                                .setPrice(Double.parseDouble(dealItem.dealPrice))
                                .setCouponCode(dealItem.couponCode)
                                .setCustomDimension(14, dealItem.store)
                                .setCustomDimension(16, "test")
                                .setCustomMetric(7, (int) 1.2);
                        tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                                .setCategory("ui_action")
                                .setAction("deal_redirect")
                                .setLabel(dealItem.dealId)
                                .addProduct(product)
                                .setCustomDimension(Constants.GA_CUSTOM_DIMENSION_PARTNER_ID, "pid")
                                .build()
                        );
```

Following is GA Log

```
04-05 16:32:18.290 D/GAv4    (10102): Hit delivery requested: 
 ht=1491390138201, _s=39, _v=ma10.2.98, a=2021803436, 
 adid=f9295aa5-f383-4835-b3d8-d50d4aabd666, 
 aid=in.ss.ss, an=ss, ate=1, av=8.0.1, 
 cd=MainActivity, cd2=mx, cid=213c230a-e45f-4930-a70f-37c57ca2cb5d, 
 ea=deal_redirect, ec=ui_action, el=4rv90qtsihl4l, pr1ca=headphone, 
 pr1cc=, pr1cd14=flipkart, pr1cd16=test, pr1cm7=1, 
 pr1id=4rv90qtsihl4l, pr1nm=JBL T250SI Stereo Wired Headphones, 
 pr1pr=749.0, sf=100.0, sr=1080x1776, t=event, tid=UA-30398300-2, 
 ul=en-us, v=1
04-05 16:32:18.376 D/GAv4    (10102): Hit sent to the device AnalyticsService for delivery
```

I have also enabled ecommerce settings in google analytics dashboard but still no data is available in dashboard. Where I can check product details in google analytics dashboard

Comment: not sure, when I send customDimensions I use to set also screenName like in example (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/customdimsmets)